# find ip address of black box device

Tags: networking, ip, aix

I have a device that I need to find the IP address of. I know that the device is an AIX host, but that is all I know. I don't know if the device is on a public or private IP address range, and I don't know the sub net mask that the device is configured with. I have hooked up a PC with wire shark to the device, and I have not seen any output when it boots up. Do you have any suggestions about what I should do to ascertain the IP address? I have considered broadcast pings and using a bulk scanner like masscan but I don't know how I should set my PCs network settings so that the packets will always be answered.

Comment: What is the model of this AIX machines, do the machine have console, do you have root password for the machine?

Comment: The machine is a power 720, but it is acting as the controller for a TS7720 virtual tape engine. Only IBM maintenance has the root passwords for those machines. I do have console access to the machine however. I can try and track down an AIX install disk to reset the root password if I had to, but I would prefer not to do it this way.

Comment: Can you login with ordinary user in AIX? And can you check the backup software, for sure you will find there the IP of the machine.

Comment: the backups are taken over Fiber Chanel, so no IP there. I will try the standard AIX user.

Comment: If you have some standard user to login you can try `netstat -rn` to see the default route. ALso you can try to switch to `root` (if `sudo` is installed) and your user have permission to switch

Comment: A console would be useful, as the system may not be booting fully.